# How to define guild in discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a command were it creates a role but gives me the error saying that guild is not defined:

```
                    guild.roles.create({
                    ^
ReferenceError: guild is not defined
```

while this is my code:

```
         guild.roles.create({
            data: {
              name: 'Boots',
              color: 'BLUE',
            },
            reason: 'very cool',
          })
            .then(console.log)
            .catch(console.error);
        
            let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Boots");

        member.roles.add(role)
        message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
        message.channel.send('Mhm, very cool');
```

Comment: You already used `message.guild`, why don't you use that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```js
message.guild.roles [...]
```

Because if you type

```js
guild.roles [...]
```

the program wants to access the `roles` property of the variable `guild`

Answer (score 0):

Did you define guild? If you want to use guild, just write something like `const guild = message.guild;`